# How do I get HDMI audio working on a Zotac MAG HD-ND01-U?

Tags: sound, nvidia, hdmi

I bought a Zotac MAG and would like all the audio to output from the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HDMI sound actually works out of the box after you install the nvidia drivers, you just need to unmute the S/PDIF microphone thing, which appears to be mislabeled.

Run `alsamixer`, then use the right arrow key to move over to it and press <kbd>M</kbd> to unmute it so the 00 shows up instead of an MM.

[image]

Comment: This method also worked for me under Oneiric (Acer Aspire 6940G).