# I can't hear sounds with Ubuntu but can with Windows

Tags: 12.04, sound

I can't hear ANY sounds whether I try to listen to music, movies, or YouTube.

My headphones are okay with Windows so please help me troubleshoot my Ubuntu set-up.

Comment: Are you dual-booting or doing the Wubi thing?

Answer (score 5):

Do you see that sound icon at the top right-hand corner of the screen? Click on it, and at the bottom of the menu that drops down, there's one labeled "Sound Settings..." Click on it. Check how many devices there are on the "Output" tab. See if changing devices helps.

[image]

If it does, congratulations, if it doesn't, change back to the original one, and keep reading.

On the "Mode" settings, there is a dropdown menu for different profiles for the selected current device. Choose another profile (e..g *"Ananlog Stereo Output"*) until you can hear the sound appropriately on the "Test Speakers" button below that.

Remember that there's no need to click "Apply" or "OK" in Ubuntu. As soon as you change something, it's applied.

If you still hear no sound you may need to install and run [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] for more options on output profiles:

[image]

If there still is no sound you may need to run `alsamixer` in a terminal to [unmute the desired output device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20303/how-do-i-get-hdmi-audio-working-on-a-zotac-mag-hd-nd01-u).

Comment: There is no *"Hardware"* tab in 12.04.

Comment: Interesting. I have it. Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that I use gnome-panel?

Comment: Yeah, this may be the case, I added the shots from 12.04 default to avoid confusion.